# How to set up liferay for team development and deployment?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, liferay, continuous-deployment, liferay-7

I am looking into how to set up a liferay project with version control and automated deployment. I have a working local development environment in eclipse, but as far as I understand it, setting up a portal in liferay is in part the liferay portal instance running on tomcat and then my custom module projects for customization. I basically want all of that in one git repository which can then be

1: cloned by any developer to set up their local dev environment

2: built and deployed by eg. jenkins into eg. AWS

I have looked at the liferay documentation regarding creating a docker container for the portal, but I don't fully understand how things like portal content would be handled.

I would be very grateful if someone could lead me in the right direction on how a environment like this would be set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code and content are different beasts. Set up a local Liferay instance for every single developer. Share/version the code through whatever version control (you mention git).

This way, every developer can work on their own project, set breakpoints, and create content that doesn't interfere with other developers.

Set up a separate integration test environment, that gets its code exclusively through your CI server, never gets touched manually.

Your production (or preproduction) database will likely have completely different content: Where a developer is quick to create a few "Lorem Ipsum" posts and pages, you don't want them to escape into production. Thus there's no movement of content from development to production. Only code moves that way.

In case you want your developers to work on a production-like environment, you can restore the production content (database) to development machines. Note that this is risky though: The database also contains user accounts, and you might trigger update notification mails from your development machines - something that you want to avoid at all costs. Plus, this way you give developers access to login data (even though it's hashed) which can be abused. And it might even be explicitly forbidden by industry regulations to use production data in development environments.

In general: Every system has its own database (at least their own schema), document store and indexing server. Every developer has their own portal JVM running. The other environments (integration test, load test, authoring, production) are also separate environments. And no, you don't need all of them all the time.

I can't attribute this quote (Milen can - see his comment), but it holds here:

> Everybody has a testing environment. Some are lucky to run a completely different production environment.

Be the lucky one. If everyone has their own fully separated environment, nobody is stepping on each other's shoes. And you'll need the integration tests (with the CI output) anyway.

Comment: The quote origin: https://twitter.com/stahnma/status/634849376343429120

Comment: Thanks, Milen. I really should have saved the attribution - already made use of it a couple of times. Now I know where to look for it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question regarding content was more on updates of the docker image. If I have a docker container running a liferay image and i want to make an update on it, what happens to the content? Is all of it saved in the database? Is the filesystem not used at all?

Comment: Everything that you want to persist (e.g. database, file storage for document library - if you configure the default, and elasticsearch's index storage) would need to be mounted as an external volume, or an external service. And yes, everything that's contained in your docker image, and not in a volume, will be back to the default once you restart the container. You probably want to whack things like DB, file storage only willingly, not on every restart - so have them external to your Docker image. And those external volumes and services will be individual per developer, not shared.

Comment: @OlafKock Thank you. Im new to docker so i hope its no bothering you too much but to be able to mount these things as external volumes I would need to know which folders of the containers file system are used for eg. file storage, is that correct? If so, is there any kind of documentation that goes more in depth with how the liferay image works?

Comment: The question is: Would you start with the Liferay image, or build your own. It's up to you and depends on the level of modifications that you do. Also: For Development I wouldn't bother setting up Docker - for me, that starts after the CI server did it's job, but that's after the developer's are no longer touching the code.

Comment: @OlafKock Sorry for the late reply. Im currently a working student and basically I was tasked with getting an overview on how the complete CI/CD process could work with Liferay. I don't do much modification so far, just a simple theme and a simple mvc-portlet should be deployed with the portal.

Comment: It's best to examine what happens outside of Docker, then remodel that within the Docker image. For simple deployment of regular plugins, it is enough to copy them into Liferay's deploy folder, and they'll be redeployed upon every start of the container. There are more options, but a comment on an answer on this question is not quite the right place for the full documentation